# Set cronjobs to run everyday at 6am in django python

Tags: python, django, cron, django-crontab

I am using Django-Crontabs to execute my function every day in the morning at 6 am. Here is my code for Django-Crontabs.

Firstly I install Django-Crontabs with this command. `pip3 install Django-crontab`

`Settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django_crontab',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'myapp'
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('* 6 * * *', 'myapp.cron.cronfunction')
]
```

Here I have set the code to run every day at 6 AM. As per the following template. But it is not working.

```
# Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

`cron.py`

```
def cronfunction():
      logger.warning("========== Run Starts ====")
      logger.warning("========== Run Ends ======")
```

If I am running this function every 2 or 3 minutes then it works fine.

```
    ('*/2 * * * *', 'myapp.cron.cronfunction')
```

How do I set my cronjob to run every day, Can anyone help? please.

Comment: * 6 * * * means running cron every minute at 6 not once at 6:00

Comment: So, how can I set cron at everyday 6 AM?

Comment: `'0 6 * * *'` This would be the way to go. Check [this visualization tool](https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_*) out! 0 specifies always at minute zero. 6 specifies always at hour six. Star means every day and month.

Comment: @Tarquinius, I will try this solution and tomorrow let you know it is working or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tarquinius, It is working properly, I got my result as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your settings.py to:

```py
# [...]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 6 * * *', 'myapp.cron.cronfunction')
]
```

0 specifies always at minute zero. 6 specifies always at hour six. Star means "every"; here day and month.

I can really recommend [this visualization tool](https://crontab.guru/#0_6_%2A_%2A_%2A) for cronjobs.

Comment: thank you @Tarquinius it worked on my system as well.